# jQuery: resizing element cuts off parent's background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been trying to recreate an effect from this tutorial: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-look-tim-van-damme/

Unfortunately, I want a background image underneath and because of the resize going on in JavaScript, it gets resized and cut off as well, like so: http://dev.gentlecode.net/dotme/index-sample.html - you can view source there to check the HTML, but basic structure looks like this:

```
<div class="page">
     <div class="container">
         div.header
         ul.nav
         div.main     
     </div> 
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$('ul.nav').each(function() {
    var $links = $(this).find('a'),
        panelIds = $links.map(function() { return this.hash; }).get().join(","),
        $panels = $(panelIds),
        $panelWrapper = $panels.filter(':first').parent(),
        delay = 500;

    $panels.hide();

    $links.click(function() {
        var $link = $(this),
            link = (this);

        if ($link.is('.current')) {
            return;
        }

        $links.removeClass('current');
        $link.addClass('current');

        $panels.animate({ opacity : 0 }, delay);
        $panelWrapper.animate({
            height: 0
        }, delay, function() {
            var height = $panels.hide().filter(link.hash).show().css('opacity', 1).outerHeight();

            $panelWrapper.animate({
                height: height
            }, delay);
        }); 
    });

    var showtab = window.location.hash ? '[hash=' + window.location.hash + ']' : ':first';

    $links.filter(showtab).click();

});
```

In this example, `panelWrapper` is a `div.main` and it gets resized to fit the content of tabs. The background is applied to the `div.page` but because its child is getting resized, it resizes as well, cutting off the background image.

It's hard to explain so please look at the link above to see what I mean.

I guess what I'm trying to ask is: is there a way to resize an element without resizing its parent? I tried setting `height` and `min-height` of `.page` to 100% and 101% but that didn't work. I tried making the background image fixed, but nada. It also happens if I add the background to the body or even html. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution could be to use jquery to set a minimum height on the `.page` element. Height must be set in pixels, not percentages. I've tested the following and it works:

```
$('.page').css('min-height',$('body').height()+'px');
```

But you will need to run this whenever the browser window is resized.

For a completely non-javascript solution you could put the bubbles in an absolutely positioned div behind the content. Use the following CSS to make the div fill the screen:

```
position:absolute;
left:0px;
right:0px;
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
z-index:1;
```

You'll have to make sure this doesn't sit on top of your page content by giving that a higher `z-index` (for `z-index` to take effect you will need to set `position:relative` or `position:absolute` on the page content)

Comment: The jQuery minimum height thing worked like a charm, and it still works after resizing window. I will test it around and either use this or the absolutely positioned div, totally didn't think of that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `min-height: 100%; background-attachment: fixed;` to the body element?

The `background-attachment` might not be needed, though.

Comment: I tried it both on body and .page (where the background actually is, body has different background) - didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the background image to the body instead of the `.page` element?

```
.page {
background: transparent url(../img/glass/bg-page.png) top center fixed no-repeat;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

The body fills the browser window but the `.page` div is only as big as its content, which is why it's getting cut off as the content animates.

Comment: "It also happens if I add the background to the body or even html." 

EDIT: Actually, when I add the bubbles background to html, it's okay. Problem is, there is another background layer (the gradient) that is supposed to be underneath and so I can't really add it to html element.

Comment: Since the gradient background on the `body` isn't getting cut off, I don't see how the bubbles background could be.

CSS3 allows for multiple background images as detailed here http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering

Comment: You can view it here: http://dev.gentlecode.net/dotme/index-body.html - gradient is set on `html` element, bubbles on `body` and it still cuts them off.